# can't pre-populate a django database

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, faker

so I've been following this guide from Django 1.1 but I'm actually using Django 2 for how to pre-populate Django database I'm using SQLite database and this is my code with Faker library but it just won't run when I want to run it in the CMD. Please help me if you can:

This is my first file which is the script for populating the database:
(populate_first_app.py)

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

## FAKE POPULATION SCRIPT:

import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord,Webpage,Topic
from faker import Faker

# Creating a fake generator:
fakegen = Faker()
topics = 

['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']
def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N = 5):

for entry in range(N):

    # GET THE TOPIC FOR THE ENTRY:
    top = add_topic()

    # Create the fake data for that entry:
    fake_url = fakegen.url()
    fake_date = fakegen.date()
    fake_name = fakegen.company()

    # Create the new webpage entry:
    webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic = top, url = fake_url, name = fake_name)[0]

    # Create a fake access record for that webpage
    acc_rec = AccessRecord.get_or_create(name = webpg, date = fake_date)[0]

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print("Populating Script!")
        populate(20)
        print("Populating Complete!")
```

And finally, this is my models.py file of the only app I have in this project:

```
    from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name

class Webpage(models.Model):
    # A Foreign key is grabbed from another table
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=None)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Webpage, on_delete=None)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        # we cast it into string because self.date is a date object
        return str(self.date)
```

Comment: What's the error? Which guide?

Comment: there are no errors it just doesn't run and there are no errors I wonder if this is about a security thing. it's a video guide that I bought from a website but it's old I mentioned in the question he was using Django 1.1

Comment: There isn't enough information to tell what's wrong and there is nothing Django 2 specific in this code. At least fix code indentation. Make sure `if __name__ == '__main__':` is not indented.

Comment: @Alireza - you might consider creating a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) for this initial data. The database tables would then get populated when you run `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 1):

I did go through your code and I found the problem why Django not creating the fake data.
You have indented the **main** function in your "populate_first_app.py". Remove the indentation and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If statement indentation wrong , nothing else

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

## FAKE POPULATION SCRIPT:

import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord,Webpage,Topic
from faker import Faker

# Creating a fake generator:
fakegen = Faker()
topics = 

['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']
def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N = 5):

for entry in range(N):

    # GET THE TOPIC FOR THE ENTRY:
    top = add_topic()

    # Create the fake data for that entry:
    fake_url = fakegen.url()
    fake_date = fakegen.date()
    fake_name = fakegen.company()

    # Create the new webpage entry:
    webpg = Webpage.objects.get_or_create(topic = top, url = fake_url, name = fake_name)[0]

    # Create a fake access record for that webpage
    acc_rec = AccessRecord.get_or_create(name = webpg, date = fake_date)[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
   print("Populating Script!")
   populate(20)
   print("Populating Complete!")
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't absolutely clear what your issue is without an error message, but my hunch is that you are failing to bootstrap the Django environment in your standalone script.

Django has a special facility for building "Commands" that you can run within the Django environment, without having to "set it up" as you are doing in populate_first_app.py.

[Django Documentation for Custom Commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/)

In your example above, you would want to move "populate_first_app.py" to be located at "first_app/management/commands/populate_first_app.py". Then you need to place your function within the BaseCommand:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from polls.models import Question as Poll
# .. other imports
class Command(BaseCommand):
   help = 'Populates test data in first_app'

   def add_arguments(self, parser):
      parser.add_argument('n', type=int)

   def handle(self, *args, **options):
      fakegen = Faker()
      for entry in range(args.n):
          #.. generate each entry
```

Once you have this command you can then run it from manage.py:

```
manage.py populate_first_app -n 20
```

The bonus is that when someone else wants to use this, they can see it when they run

manage.py help

Comment: so I've got that sorted out but I've got an error this time! which is an import error that says can't import 'Faker' from 'faker' !

Comment: How did you install "faker"? Did you do it with "pip install faker"?

Answer (score 0):

first you need to do `python manage.py migrate`

and then respectively `python manage.py makemigrations`

then give some suggestion like that... AccessRecort change to AccessRecord [y/N]?
press y

then `python mange.py migrate`

> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: admin, auth,
>   contenttypes, first_app, sessions Running migrations:   Applying
>   first_app.0002_auto_20190731_1445... OK

```
(MyDjangoEnv) C:\your\file\path\first_project>python populate_first_app.py
```

Populating Script!

Populating complete!